# Command(s) which would render a LaTeX document into a PNG on Mac

Tags: png

I am using TexShop on a Mac, which handles all of the rendering for me, but have been asked by a colleague to find the command(s) that would render the LaTex document as a PNG instead of PDF.

By way of example, on linux it would be

```
$ pdflatex file.tex
$ gs -sDEVICE=pnggray -sOutputFile=card.png -dNOPAUSE -r1200 file.pdf quit.ps
```

(Note: the -r1200 will generate an image 4x larger than used, since it will be scaled down to produce an anti-aliased image).

Thank you & kind regards.

Comment: OSX is unix, so you can probably issue the GS command the same way.

Comment: You can use `convert`.

Comment: where did the file `quit.ps` come from in the command you show? Is this command supposed to convert a PDF file to PNG image? So a 100 pages pdf file will be converted to one png image? becuase when I just tried it on 16 pages pdf file: `gs -sDEVICE=pnggray -sOutputFile=card.png -dNOPAUSE -r1200 index.pdf` then when it is done, I get the `GS>` prompt. Now I typed `quit` and then looked at `card.png` but it only shows the first page of the pdf file only.  How is this supposed to work?

Comment: There are two commands: `sips` and `convert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mac OS is Unix-based, so at the Terminal

```
pdflatex <filename> && gs -sDEVICE=pnggray -sBATCH -sOutputFile=<filename>.png -dNOPAUSE -r1200 <filename>.pdf
```

should work just fine. (Fill in your `<filename>`, of course.)

Comment: is this equivalent to opening the PDF in Preview and exporting as png?